Do people with special needs have a higher soul?

Is it true that people with special needs have a higher soul according to Kabbalah?
Is this only true for a Jewish soul or can it also be possible for a non-Jew (e.g. pre-convert, Noahide or any non-Jew)?


For your first question see my answer here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/133979/free-will-of-people-with-mental-disorders/133990#133990 which actually implies the opposite

I don't know if this means anything, but an anecdote: R' Shach zt"l used to stand up for my Down Syndrome uncle (at the time in his late teens) when he entered the room.

You might wish to read the book: Galia, Messages from Heaven (its still available, like on Amazon etc.)

https://youtu.be/fBjUmj95r6g?si=tE9wi-l6-JxBFxbj

This book, the autobiography of a young French woman so severely disabled that she had to manipulate a special device with her mouth to write it, would appear to suggest that. She died before her 20th birthday and could clearly remember her last few reincarnations and those of her brother, in addition to lucidly explaining many aspects of Sod Hatorah. The book was endorsed by the Chief Rabbi of France, who also wrote the forward.

According to the Amazon description, this was done using facilitated communication. The rabbi's endorsement notwithstanding, in many cases, the way this is done has the non-disabled facilitator unwittingly producing the text, much like an Ouija board. https://www.amazon.fr/livre-dAnna%C3%ABlle-Anna%C3%ABlle-Chimoni/dp/2268033694

That is a valuable piece of information, @joshwaxman, thank you for bringing it. Not sure what to make of it given Rabbi Sitruc's recommendation (he was a remarkable figure who brought thousands of people from kiddish-and-TV on Friday nights to shemirat mitzvot).
